# Configure retrieved data from web service

Tags: android, json, soap

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/xxxx/GetLatLong";

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetLatLong";

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

private static final String URL = "http://xxxx:xxxx/xxxx.svc/soap";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    setContentView(textView);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);



    try

    {


        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  


        Object response = envelope.getResponse();



        textView.setText(response.toString());


    }

    catch (Exception exception)

    {

        textView.setText(exception.toString());

    }


}
```

}

This is an example of my code. 
This returns a string with 3 data description latitude and longitude .

I want to handle them separately how can I manage this ?
I want to put it then on a map with that configuration.

Comment: Please provide the response string..

Comment: [{"Description":"1","Latitude":0.369,"Longitude":1.258},{"Description":"2","Latitude":1.369,"Longitude":3.258},{"Description":"3","Latitude":2.369,"Longitude":4.258}]

Answer (score 0):

Write code something like this

```
 JSONArray array=new JSONArray("your string response in json format");
    for(int count=0;count<array.length();count++)
    {
            JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(count);
            String description=obj.optString("Description");
            String latitude=obj.optString("Latitude");
            String longitude=obj.optString("Longitude");

            // Logic to display latlong on map
    }
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Update your parser's code in question, and give me the line number of error.

Comment: use like this instead of optString .. String description=obj.getString("Description");

Comment: org.json.jsonexception value any type of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Comment: i have used your code writen up i changed optstring to getString and again im getting error  soapObject cannot be cast to java.lang.string

Comment: First try to convert your response into string format, than only try parsing. And show me updated parsing code, my code is just a guideline. I want to see what exactly you are passing in new JSONArray("your string response in json format");